# Time complexity of for loops in Java

Tags: java, arrays, time-complexity, big-o

I have started learning Big O notation and analysing time complexities, and I tried messing around with some code to try and understand its time complexity. Here's one of the lines that I had, but I can't seem to figure out what the time complexity for the sum method is? I reckon it is o(n^3) but my friend says it should be o(n^2). Any insights as to what is the right answer?

```
public static double sum(double[] array)
{
   double sum = 0.0;
   for(int k = 0; k < size(array); k++)
       sum = sum + get(array, k);
   return sum;
}

public static double get(double[] array, int k)
{
   for(int x=0; x < k; x++)
       if(x==k) return array[k];
   return -1;
}

public static int size(double[] array)
{
   int size = 0;
   for(int k=0; k<array.length; k++)
       size++;
   return size;
   
}
```

Comment: `size()` is O(n); `get()` is `O(n)`. You are executing `size()` on each iteration of a loop which runs `size()` times; and inside the loop you execute `get()` on each iteration. So it's O(n^3).

Answer (score 1):

I guess you friend is right, time complexity is `O(n^2)`.
Because on each iteration in your loop, you consequently calculate `size()`, which is order of `O(n)`, and calculate `get()`, which on average is `O(n/2)`.
So each iteration's complexity is `O(1.5 * n)` and overall is `O(n^2)`

Comment: You said get is **on average** O(n/2), but if we are looking at worst case scenario, would it still be O(n^2)? Or am I confusing the concepts here?

Comment: So for `get` the worst call would be that of k = n - 1 and best would be n = 0, but usullly we just take the average which is n/2.